# Bigquery Pseudo_ID distinct count much lower than Firebase users

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery

The user pseudo_ID count in Bigquery is much smaller than the number of users on Firebase. I read similar posts on this discrepancy but it seems that my discrepancy is much bigger. My ultimate objective is to collect usage data in a specific city by pseudo_ID; however, it seems that Bigquery is not showing all the pseudo_IDs. I am not sure what went wrong and how I should fix it. Is my syntax incorrect? Or am I misunderstanding anything?

This is an example of my query for one day,
which from my understanding it should count the total distinct users in the U.S.
on 2021-02-04.

```
SELECT count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as users
FROM scratchjr-app.analytics_210555769.events_20210204 
WHERE 1=1 AND DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) = '2021-02-04' AND geo.country = 'United States'
```

This is the result,

[
{
"users": "3908"
}
]

However, the number on the Firebase portal shows that users on this day in the U.S. should be 85,069.
I have been getting this discrepancy for all the days and not only on this day. I would highly appreciate any suggestions!

[Firebase portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRkjo.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Export distinct user_ids from Google and do `select ... where user_id not in <your exported set>` in Firebase. This will give you a starting point

Comment: @astentx Thank you so much for your suggestion! I did not set up user_ids on the Firebase portal that's why I had to use user_pseudo ID on bigquery. Is that a problem? Also, there is no place to find user_pseudoID on Firebase portal for me to export as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, cannot tell you what is the problem. You should have some glue to match BigQuery's data and Firebase's data. I've thought that `user_pseudoID` is it.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. I will keep looking at how I can compare the two. But I am also still open to more suggestions or solutions.